# javascript - overriden method

Tags: javascript

```
var A = {
   method1 : function(){
      // do some thing
   },

   method2 : function(){
      // do some thing
   }
};

var B = {
  method1 : function(){
   // overriden
  }
};
```

how to overriden ?

```
B.extend(B, A);
```

or

```
B.merge(A);
```

What is the right way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to create a new object that has all the properties of `B` and inherits from `A`.

E.g.

```
function extend(B, A) {
    var Constr = function() {
        for(var prop in B) {
            if(B.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
                this[prop] = B[prop];
            }
        }
    };
    Constr.prototype = A;
    return new Constr(); 
}
```

Then you can do:

```
B = extend({
  method1 : function(){
     // overriden
  }
}, A);
```

`A`'s methods are unchanged and you don't need an external library ;)

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/L7bDd/)

Answer (score 1):

Well, you extend the class/object.

I would take a look at the jQuery extend.
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/

That can be used easely to extend your classes/object.

Example:

```
var A = {
    methode1: function(){
        // Do something
    }
    methode2: function(){
        // Do something else
    }
}

var B = {
    methode1: function() {
        // Do something different then A.methode1
    }
}
var object = $.extend(true, A, B);
```

Comment: Sorry, i come from a java background where you extend classes rather then objects ;). But it's used to extend an 'object' in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

In its present form i don't see how `B` is in any way related to object `A` [so there's no question of overriding there].

if you really want to have something along the line of inheritance:

```
var B = A
B.method1 = function() { 
    // overriding
}
```

so that, invoking `B.method2()` gets you `A's` method, while `method1()` gets overriden by `B's` version.

Comment: thank for suggestion , if follow your way, i always include A, but i don't want . try to imagine what happens if i have 50 function need overriden :( . I want put them in an object

Comment: I've had a problem with that however. Making the A.method1 equal to B.methode1.