# javascript: casting an object that has been created with eval

Tags: javascript, eval

I have a set of javascript classes that I use throughout my app. In one case I want to eval some json from an ajax response whose shape matches one of my classes.

I'm using the jquery parseJSON method to do the eval for me.

The only problem is I now want to call a method defined in my class however I know that method won't exist on the eval'd object.

What's the nicest way to make this method available on my new object. Is there a way to "cast" it?

Comment: I've wondered this myself for quite a while.

Comment: Have a look at [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5063558/javascript-overriden-method/5063837#5063837). You could use this to extend the the object you get from JSON with the prototype of your "class". (or just copy the data from the JSON to an object of your "class" as @Box9 nicely demonstrates ;))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no concept of casting in JavaScript. Instead, you can modify your class' constructor to accept a plain object. How you do this depends on how you've set up your class, but could simply involve a shallow copy of the object into a new instance of the class:

```
var MyClass = function (obj) {
    for (var i in obj) {
        if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) continue;
        this[i] = obj[i];
    }
    // Other class initialisation code
};
```

Then "cast" your object like this:

```
var result = new MyClass(someObject);
```

If you have multiple classes that require this, you may prefer to create an `extend` function that does the cloning for you (or if you're using jQuery, this function already exists):

```
var extend = function (obj1, obj2) {
    for (var i in obj2) {
        if (!obj2.hasOwnProperty(i)) continue;
        obj1[i] = obj2[i];
    }
};
```

And then "cast" like this:

```
var result = new MyClass();
extend(result, someObject);
```

Comment: Otherwise known as serialize and de-serialize your objects.

Comment: interesting, although I'm not sure about this bit "var result = new MyClass(someJson);" surely the "someJSON" will either need to be eval'd in the constructor or it will already be eval'd in which case it should be called "someObject"?

Comment: @Raynos, not really. The OP has already deserialised it using `parseJSON` - he needs a way to copy this into an instance of some class.

Comment: @Chris you're right it should be `someObject`, I assumed it was already passed through `parseJSON`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've added fromJSON methods to my base classes so I don't have to repeat this code and used the jquery extend function as suggested. Perfect.